# web api validation messages for one section display before application form is submitted

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am try to deal with a bug on one of the sections for the application form I am currently developing in order to explain my issue the screenshots below show the workflow for this section:

[image]

When you first navigate to the section you are presented with this screen you then chose an option from the dropdownlist and click next.

When you click next the form values for the option selected are generated as below:

[image]

the problem comes when you change the option, when the new option form values are generated errors for the previous option are being generated as shown below:

[image]

to explain some of the logic when the next or change button is clicked it posts back to an actionresult in the corresponding applycontroller in the actionresult it posts the option value to a web api which saves the data to the database the code below is performing this task:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AdmissionsTest(AdmissionsTestViewModel model, ApplyService service, string programmeDesc, int? programmeId, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        Guid applicationId = (Guid)TempData["ApplicationId"];

        TempData["ApplicationId"] = applicationId;

        model.ApplicationValidations = (ICollection<ApplicationValidation>)TempData["ApplicationValidations"];

        TempData["ApplicationValidations"] = model.ApplicationValidations;

        model.ApplicationProgrammeDetails = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationProgrammeDetailsViewModel>();

        if (programmeId != null)
        {
            Programme programme = service.GetProgramme(model.ProgrammeId);

            model.ApplicationProgrammeDetails.ProgrammeDesc = programme.ProgrammeDesc;
        }
        else
        {
            model.ApplicationProgrammeDetails.ProgrammeDesc = programmeDesc;
        }

        foreach (var item in formCollection.AllKeys)
        {
            if ((model.AdmissionsTestOptionId == null) && (item.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("submitbuttonnext") || (item.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("submitbuttonchange"))))
            {
                model.ApplicationId = applicationId;

                model.NavButton = "10";

                await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail/UpdateApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail", model)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

                return View("AdmissionsTest", model);
            }
            if ((model.AdmissionsTestOptionId == 1) && (item.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("submitbuttonnext") || (item.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("submitbuttonchange"))))
            {
                model.ApplicationId = applicationId;

                model.NavButton = "10";

                await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail/UpdateApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail", model)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

                return View("AdmissionsTest", model);
            }
            if ((model.AdmissionsTestOptionId == 2) && (item.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("submitbuttonnext") || (item.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("submitbuttonchange"))))
            {
                model.ApplicationId = applicationId;

                model.NavButton = "10";

                await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail/UpdateApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail", model)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

                return View("AdmissionsTest", model);
            }
            if ((model.AdmissionsTestOptionId == 3) && (item.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("submitbuttonnext")))
            {
                model.ApplicationId = applicationId;

                await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail/UpdateApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail", model)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

                if (model.NavButton == null) { model.NavButton = "11"; }
                return NavigateToStage(model.NavButton);
            }
            if ((model.AdmissionsTestOptionId == 3) && (item.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("submitbuttonchange")))
            {
                model.ApplicationId = applicationId;

                model.NavButton = "10";

                await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail/UpdateApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail", model)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

                return View("AdmissionsTest", model);
            }
        }

         //save

        string dateGMATTaken = model.DateGMATTakenDay + "/" + model.DateGMATTakenMonth + "/" + model.DateGMATTakenYear;

        string dateGRETaken = model.DateGRETakenDay + "/" + model.DateGRETakenMonth + "/" + model.DateGRETakenYear;

        DateTime dateOfGMATTestTaken;

        DateTime dateOfGRETestTaken;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateGMATTaken, out dateOfGMATTestTaken))
        {
            model.GMATDateTaken = dateOfGMATTestTaken;
        }
        else
        {
            model.GMATDateTaken = null;
        }

        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateGRETaken, out dateOfGRETestTaken))
        {
            model.GREDateTaken = dateOfGRETestTaken;
        }
        else
        {
            model.GREDateTaken = null;
        }

        model.ApplicationId = applicationId;

        await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail/UpdateApplicationAdmissionsTestDetail", model)
           .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

        //redirect based on submit

        if (model.NavButton == null) { model.NavButton = "11"; }
        return NavigateToStage(model.NavButton);
    }
```

I have tested the actionresult using break points to see if it might be going to the final submit action but so far it appears to be staying within the actionresult I have also used fiddler to see if the submit method on the web api is being called this has also return blank.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have modified the return value so instead of returning `return View()` they now use `return RedirectToRoute()` which has resolved the bug